# Why is pandas data frame becoming a NoneType object?

Tags: python, pandas

I am struggling to determine why I am receiving this error in python. In my code, I merged two data frames in pandas:

```
result = pd.merge(credit_record, application_record, on="ID")
```

and then dropped rows that have missing values in a particular column:

```
new_data = result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"], inplace=True)
```

I then tried to view my updated data frame and received an error:

```
new_data.head()
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I've never used pandas, but I think the result.dropna([...]) with the inplace argument set to `True`  modify the result directly and didn't return anything, try `print(result.head())` or remove the `inplace=True`

Comment: Please Add ```result.dtypes``` to your question. along with total records and sample data.

Answer (score 2):

When you use **inplace** parameter the function works on the Original Dataframe **result** here, try this

```
result = pd.merge(credit_record, application_record, on="ID")
new_data = result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"])
new_data.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

`Inplace=True` indicates that the drop will be operated on the result dataframe [see documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html). So you arent copying the dataframe to new_data. So this results in an ampty Dataframe.
Remove `inplace=True` and it will work fine.

```
result = pd.merge(credit_record, application_record, on="ID")
new_data = result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"])
new_data.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

`new_data = result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"], inplace=True)`

When you use **(inplace=True)** it returns a null-type object.
**Remove (inplace=True)** and the try.

`new_data = result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"]`

Answer (score 1):

Just FYI you can also just just keep your code the way it is but just not store your dataframe in a new variable.  So pretty much same thing the other commenters are saying regarding `inplace=True` so instead of excluding this parameter you would just write your code like this:

```
result = pd.merge(credit_record, application_record, on="ID")
result.dropna(subset = ["MONTHS_BALANCE"], inplace=True)
result.head()
```